Почему иногда не ставят запятую в сочетании "для тех кто"?
В Карте слов много таких примеров.
Для тех кто строит системный бизнес и хочет, чтобы он развивался после ухода из него. Вячеслав Владимирович Богданов, Матрица эффективного окружения.
Хорошее место для охотников и рыбаков и просто для тех кто ценит настоящий отдых. Галина Владимировна Коршунова, Карелия. Отдых.
Есть даже песня Для тех кто
Это новая тенденция?
Конечно, это всего лишь популярная литература  на разные темы, но форма такого письма становится привычной.
P. S. Интересно, что в Сети много вопросов про эту запятую. Все уверенно отвечают, что запятая нужна, но их доказательства не убеждают. Как говорится, размазаны как манная каша по тарелке, и все примеры не в тему.  Такое впечатление, что отвечающие понимают обоснованность сомнений, но не понимают их причину.

Надо бы метку изменить. Я бы поправила, но не знаю, какую Вы имели в виду.

Ну не знаю... Попробую собрать манную кашу...
• В "Литературной энциклопедии" есть такая информация:

указательные местоимения — разряд местоимений, указывающих на конкретные реалии: то/это, тот/этот, такой, столько, так, там, туда, оттуда, тогда, потому, затем. В речи сопровождаются жестами. Вместе с относительными местоимениями участвуют в связи частей сложного предложения: там/где, тот/кто.

Может, есть еще где — не знаю. Но этого, думаю, вполне достаточно, что ставить запятую между "тех" и "кто".
• "Карта слов" — это неплохой ресурс, но примеры оттуда нужно брать с "осторожностию великою". Вот, например, предложения с сочетанием за тех кто.

Дела богов непостижимы человеку, и нечего ему лезть туда где он может нарушить течение замыслов великих, но как порой мальчишкам хочется заглянуть туда где богами куются чудеса, а такие события как сегодня, так и просят осторожненько подглядеть за теми кто сегодня решил собрать над запретными землями все облака с неба.

Честное слово, даже если «Побочная Личность» интересна и популярна, читать я ее не буду — во избежание глобального раздражения от повсеместного отсутствия нужных запятых и присутствия ненужных.
• Что до песен... Не стоит принимать во внимание никому не известную композицию, в тексте которой нет ни одной точки — ни правильной, ни неправильной.
Надо ориентироваться на классику — тут все знаки на своих местах (За тех, кто в море):
Я пью до дна
За тех, кто в море,
За тех, кого любит волна,
За тех, кому повезет.
• На всякого рода тенденции, связанные с грамотностью, мне кажется, также влияет привычка писать быстро в телефонах и компьютерах и отсутствие практики чтения вслух.

Местоимения, да, с ними проблем хватает)  Но тут такое дело, произношение надо учитывать. Ведь не зря же сложные союзы именно в начале предложения не расчленяются, а в конце  предложения это норма.// Отчего мы не можем так же поступить со сложным союзным соединением  "для тех кто", кто же нам запрещает. Конечно, отчасти грамматика будет некорректной, но разве такое не случается в языке? Есть устойчивые сочетания, а иногда придаточное ставится в середину главного: Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался.

А все это ради правильного произношения. Вот и здесь: зачем нам пауза после предложной формы "для тех" в начале фразы, ее там очевидно нет.  // Опять же Грамота допускает нерасчленение сочетания "то что надо". После такой массовой ошибки я даже поискала у них информацию на эту тему.  Я думаю, что сказывается расчленение подобных сложных союзов.

Могу высказать свою версию ответа.

Я полагаю, пользователи считают, что это сложный союз, который они могут не расчленять по образцу союза для того чтобы.

Но здесь другой вид связи, и он подробно рассматривается в теме.


Это не сложный союз, а сложное местоименное соединение, которое по структуре напоминает такой союз. Здесь местоименное указательное слово, поэтому запятая должна стоять.

В то же время в начале предложения расчленение союзного соединения выглядит странно, особенно в названии (номинативная конструкция): Для тех кто строит системный бИзнес / и хочет, чтобы он развивался после ухОда из него.

Здесь ударение явно уходит в конец фразы, поэтому пауза в начале предложения выглядит неестественно.
